# How to encode MP3 in MPEG elementary audio file?

Tags: iphone, http-live-streaming

How to encode MP3 in MPEG elementary audio file? i want to stream an MP3 audio file from web server to iPhone. As per the procedure shown in Apple document,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH101-SW3
they say that the media encoder takes a real-time signal from an audio-video device, encodes the media, and encapsulates it for transport. Now my doubt is how to encode a media file? for example if MP3 is the audio file, i need to encode it into MPEG Elementary Audio file. How to achive it?? please help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) or write an application yourself and use [LAME library](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) to do MP3 encoding.